# .htaccess URL Rewrite Help for .php extension

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am new and beginner for URL Rewrite...
I need to remove .php extension for these pages for menu links.

```
<ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="services.php">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="rates.php">Rates</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.php#main">Contact Us</a></li>
 </ul>
```

I am using the following code for .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
# Remove .php-extension from url
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
  RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ $1.php
# End of Apache Rewrite Rules
 </IfModule>
```

For example:

```
localhost/websitename/index.php
```

to

localhost/websitename/index

```
localhost/websitename/about.php
```

to

localhost/websitename/about

```
localhost/websitename/services.php
```

to

localhost/websitename/services

```
localhost/websitename/rates.php
```

to

localhost/websitename/rates

```
localhost/websitename/contact.php#main
```

to

localhost/websitename/contact-main

But the following Rewrite Rule is showing the result like this

```
localhost/websitename/services.php
```

to 
`localhost/services` ........... ERROR: Page not Found
.
.
.
.
.
so on and on...

What I am doing wrong?
How can I achieve this simple URL Rewrite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For hiding `.php` extension replace your code with this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/gta/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /gta/$1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks! alot it is exactly what I needed. I have checked on the hosting server... its showing [link]http://domain.com/abc/index [/link]

Comment: Thanks! alot it is exactly what I needed. I have checked on the hosting server... its showing (http://domain.com/abc/index) but **(404 Page Not Found ERROR)**. Can you please let me know what I am missing again? As the Menu links on the web pages are as same as I mentioned you earlier on my post like  `<ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="services.php">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="rates.php">Rates</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.php#main">Contact Us</a></li>
 </ul>`

Comment: ! What I am missing... any idea?

Comment: .htaccess is locating on the document root of the website directory and Yes! page not showing... as the physical path of the page on the MENU LINKS are correct. And The directories and files order on the hosting server is like `public_html/.htaccess,public_html/index.php,public_html/about.php,public_html/s‌​ervices.php,public_html/rates.php,public_html/contact.php,public_html/css/,public‌​_html/js/,public_html/images/`

Comment: When I access the page `yourdomain.com/about.php` via click on the menu link of the index page... it send me to `yourdomain.com/about` but its shows me nothing and simply**404 page not found** error message display.

Comment: Ok, Post your latest .htaccess in your question.

Comment: `Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /gta/

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]`

Comment: Ah you never told me about `gta` folder :) Let me edit the answer then.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're just missing part of the path to your file on disk:

```
  RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ websitename/$1.php
```